# Simplifying JSON by extracting fields with values

Tags: json

Looking to restructure a JSON file to a simpler format so I can ingest it to Azure Data Explorer.
I have a 600MB JSON with around 13 million records that I would need to simplify in order to properly ingest it to ADX. At the moment each record has a lot of child nodes with values.

Each record in the JSON file is structured like this

```
{
    "Event": {
        "EventData": {
            "FileName": "\\Device\\HarddiskVolume3\\Windows\\Prefetch\\CALCULATORAPP.EXE-BD3622F6.pf",
            "FileObject": "0xFFFF93079D667A00"
        },
        "ExtendedTracingInfo": {
            "EventGuid": "{90cbdc39-4a3e-11d1-84f4-0000f80464e3}"
        },
        "ExtendedTracingInfo_attributes": {
            "xmlns": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace"
        },
        "RenderingInfo": {
            "EventName": "FileIo",
            "EventName_attributes": {
                "xmlns": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace"
            },
            "Opcode": "FileCreate",
            "Provider": "MSNT_SystemTrace"
        },
        "RenderingInfo_attributes": {
            "Culture": "en-GB"
        },
        "System": {
            "Channel": null,
            "Computer": null,
            "Correlation_attributes": {
                "ActivityID": "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}"
            },
            "EventID": "0",
            "Execution_attributes": {
                "KernelTime": "0",
                "ProcessID": "4294967295",
                "ProcessorID": "0",
                "ThreadID": "4294967295",
                "UserTime": "0"
            },
            "Keywords": "0x0",
            "Level": "0",
            "Opcode": "32",
            "Provider_attributes": {
                "Guid": "{9e814aad-3204-11d2-9a82-006008a86939}"
            },
            "Task": "0",
            "TimeCreated_attributes": {
                "SystemTime": "2023-06-28T09:15:36.610881300Z"
            },
            "Version": "2"
        }
    },
    "Event_attributes": {
        "xmlns": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event"
    }
}
```

and I am looking to structure it like this

```
  "FileName": "\\Device\\HarddiskVolume3\\Windows\\Prefetch\\CALCULATORAPP.EXE-BD3622F6.pf",
  "FileObject": "0xFFFF93079D667A00",
  "EventGuid": "{90cbdc39-4a3e-11d1-84f4-0000f80464e3}",
  "xmlns": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event",
  "EventName": "FileIo",
  "Opcode": "32",
  "Provider": "MSNT_SystemTrace",
  "Culture": "en-GB",
  "Channel": null,
  "Computer": null,
  "ActivityID": "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}",
  "EventID": "0",
  "ProcessID": "4294967295",
  "ProcessorID": "0",
  "ThreadID": "4294967295",
  "UserTime": "0",
  "Keywords": "0x0",
  "Level": "0",
  "Guid": "{9e814aad-3204-11d2-9a82-006008a86939}",
  "Task": "0",
  "SystemTime": "2023-06-28T09:15:36.610881300Z",
  "Version": "2"
}
```

I realize that there are fields like xmlns and opcode but really I care about one OpCode so would like it rename it to RenderingInfo_OpCode and System_Opcode